# Are photons absorbed by Sun’s hydrogen atom all emitted by other Hydrogen atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, spectroscopy

Apologies if this is a stupid question.

1. There are absorption lines in Sun’s spectrum which means many photons with a specific energy, say $E$, are absorbed by e.g. hydrogen atoms.
2. Thermal radiation from the Sun form a continuous spectrum. While many thermal photons have energy close to $E$, none of them is exactly $E$ and by Quantum Mechanics cannot be absorbed by hydrogen.

Therefore the photons of energy $E$ absorbed by Sun’s hydrogen atoms must come from emission by other hydrogen atoms. Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can take a black body source like a tungsten filament or a hot piece of Silicon Carbide that has no hydrogen and produce a broad spectrum of radiation that overlaps the absorption lines of hydrogen. If I place an optical cell with hydrogen gas in between the source and a spectrometer, I will find that black body spectrum will have have been absorbed corresponding to  the energy levels of the hydrogen atom.

So no, to be absorbed the source of the radiation doesn't need to come from the element producing the light.

Also when we talk about the energy levels of atom being discrete, they are not infinitely sharp. They still have a line width, different energy levels can have different line widths partly depending on the quantum mechanics of the atom but also depending on the local environment, e.g. gas pressure, electric and magnetic fields, temperature etc. So the probability of absorption also turns out to be influenced by the line shape of the energy level.

Comment: Thank you.  

Say e.g. hydrogen atoms absorb photons of energy $E=E_1-E_0$ (where $E_0, E_1$ are energy levels of hydrogen). You mentioned [to be absorbed the source of the radiation doesn't need to come from the element producing the light].
Am I understand correctly that hydrogen atom can absorb thermal photons with energy slightly different from $E$ with high probability, e.g. within $(E-\epsilon, E+\epsilon)$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, the photon could be produced by any method, it would need to have the right energy within in linewidth to be absorbed with some probability.  In more complicated cases like if your hydrogen atom was also in a magnetic field you might also be concerned with the polarization of the light to to interact with the spin of the electron in some way.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Curious any good reference that calculates the line width for e.g. the 656nm hydrogen red line?

Comment: And you mention spectral lines not infinitely sharp partly due to quantum mechanics. Could you elaborate more?  Is it related to uncertainty principle (e.g. uncertainty of energy)?

Comment: http://www-star.st-and.ac.uk/~kw25/teaching/nebulae/lecture08_linewidths.pdf is a high level description.